# Issue with Tibco EMS connection

Tags: jms, tibco

I am looking at a Java application which listens to a Tibco queue. The application has not been touched for 4 years, but I see an intermittent issue in the client log where a connection get terminated. I am new to Tibco and JMS.

Can someone shed any light on it? Below is the exception message I see in the log:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: Connection has been terminated
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsSession._getSyncMessage(TibjmsSession.java:1845)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsSession._receive(TibjmsSession.java:1735)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsMessageConsumer._receive(TibjmsMessageConsumer.java:209)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsMessageConsumer.receive(TibjmsMessageConsumer.java:355)
```

Comment: The exception is usually indicates network issue. May be because of TibcoEMS and Java application are not in same network, installed to Virtual servers, has firewall between servers etc I would start with network diagnostic first.

Answer (score 1):

I am familiar with JMS, but not with Tibco. The stack-trace indicates the problem is occurring when the client invokes `javax.jms.MessageConsumer.receive()`. This call goes into the Tibco JMS client implementation which results in the `Connection has been terminated` message. The JMS specification doesn't define the error messages which accompany JMS exceptions so this message is coming specifically from the Tibco implementation. My guess is that there was a network error or perhaps a connection timeout.

I recommend you check the Tibco EMS server logs to see if there are any corresponding errors logged there and follow up directly with Tibco to see what situations could lead to this particular message. Tibco EMS isn't open source like, for example, ActiveMQ so it's impossible for someone like me to dig into the code and figure out what exactly is happening.